# Using ECharts Service with Karma Testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, echarts

In my component I have this as the constructor:

`constructor(private es: NgxEchartsService, private sessionService: SessionService, private sorting: SortingService) { }`

And, the first line that I have on my `onInit()` is:
`this.es.registerMap('world', worldJson);`
For the world map chart. It works perfectly, but with this `.spec.ts`:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { UsersViewComponent } from './users-view.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { MyDateRangePickerModule } from '../../../node_modules/mydaterangepicker';
import { NgxEchartsModule, NgxEchartsService } from '../../../node_modules/ngx-echarts';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { SessionService } from '../Services/session.service';
import { SortingService } from '../sorting.service';

describe('UsersViewComponent', () => {
  let component: UsersViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UsersViewComponent>;



  function fireEvent(id,event){
    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const button = nativeElement.querySelector('#'+id);
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event(event));
  }

  beforeEach(() => {

    // Create a fake TwainService object with a `getQuote()` spy
    const sessionService = jasmine.createSpyObj('sessionService', ['getSessions']);
    // Make the spy return a synchronous Observable with the test data
    var getSessionSpy = sessionService.getSessions.and.returnValue(Observable.of({}));;


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MyDateRangePickerModule, NgxEchartsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [UsersViewComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NgxEchartsService},
        { provide: SessionService, useValue: sessionService },
        { provide: SortingService }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fireEvent("worldMapChart","chartInit");

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

it gives me: Cannot read property 'registerMap' of undefined, meaning that the Service is not being correctly passed to the component. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not mocking any `service (providers)`, then you may simply specify them at the root of `providers` array.

```
providers: [
        NgxEchartsService,
        { provide: SessionService, useValue: sessionService },
        SortingService
      ]
```